# How do you pass a value into an ajax listener primefaces

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

So I have

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{refriedBean.onTabChange}" />
```

But I want to pass in the tabChange event AND an extra value that is stored on the page

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event, Object obj)
```

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can replace argument `obj` with additional property in bean and set needed value to this property on ajax request:

```
<p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{refriedBean.onTabChange}">
  <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{refriedBean.additionalProperty}" value="value_here"/>
</p:ajax>
```

See [setPropertyActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html)

Comment: Nesting is by the way not necessary. It will be applied to the parent component anyway.

Comment: It does have to be nested cause the parent must be of type ActionSource. Also It does not seem to be working. I made a value called additionalProperty in refriedBean and gave it a getter and setter.

Comment: @Angelo.Hannes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876257/fsetpropertyactionlistener-doesnt-set-the-value-however-action-is-triggered

Comment: I don´t understand why this answer is upvoted. I just wanted to refer to the same Link like akapelko....

Comment: It doesn't work for me either. Bean property is not set before listener handler.