# f:setPropertyActionListener doesn't set the value however action is triggered

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need to set a boolean field whenever `p:fieldset` is toggled. I tried out following code but the field is never set by f:setPropertyActionListener  although p:ajax listener is invoked on toggle. I tried out following code.

```
    <p:fieldset legend="(Optional) Link.." toggleable="true">
        <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="..">
            <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{viewScope.rendrUsrProjctsList}" value="#{true}"/>
        </p:ajax>
    </p:fieldset>
```

However when I tried modifying the code as below then field is successfully set:

```
    <p:fieldset legend="(Optional) Link.." toggleable="true">
        <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{view.viewMap.put('rendrUsrProjctsList', true)}" />
        <p:ajax event="toggle" listener=".."/>
        </p:ajax>
    </p:fieldset>
```

I want to ask:

1. Why 1st way doesn't work ?
2. Is it bad attaching multiple `p:ajax` to
   single parent as done in 2nd way ?

Comment: "#{true}" ?? - use "true"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`<f:setPropertyActionListener>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html) works as being an [`ActionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html) implementation only on components implementing [`ActionSource`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/ActionSource.html) interface, such as [`UICommand`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html), i.e. `<h:commandXxx>`, `<p:commandXxx>`, etc. The `<p:ajax>` does not implement this interface and therefore the `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` is basically completely ignored.

As to your workaround, you could do so although I'd rather just use a concrete view scoped bean or wrap it in a composite with a backing component.

Comment: Hi BalisC, that's great, but its not mentioned on the OracleDocs http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/setPropertyActionListener.html

Comment: @KishorP: I quote from your link: *"... registers it on the ActionSource associated with our most immediate surrounding instance..."* See also 1st link in my answer (it already points to that resource).

Comment: Thanks very much BalusC :)