# Get rowIndex via RowEditEvent

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a simple question but I was unable to find the right answer.

I render a datatable which is pretty complex:

```
<p:dataTable var="label" value="#{labelsManager.labelsList}" rowKey="#{label.cod}" editable="true"
                                rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15,30" paginator="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" rows="30"
                                paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                                rendered="#{not empty labelsManager.labelsList}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="300" id="labelsList" sortMode="multiple"
                                selection="#{labelsManager.selectedLabelsForDelete}">
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{labelsManager.onRowEdit}" />
...some code...
</dataTable>
```

and a method

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
 ... here I want to get the index on the current row...
}
```

When I want to edit a row I want also to get the index of the current row which will be edited. I searched a lot but I can't see how I can extract the id from the RowEditEvent.

I also tried to sent as an attribute the index of the row but without success. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: I want to get the id of one cell from the row which it will be updated which is created dynamic. Eg (tableForm:labelsList:1:myId) where 1 is rowIndex

Comment: You could use `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to set the rowIndex value in your bean, have you tried this?

Comment: Yes I already tried to put on rowEditor <f:setPropertyActionListener> but I get an error like "<f:setPropertyActionListener> Parent is not of type ActionSource, type is: org.primefaces.component.roweditor.RowEditor@38523852
"

Comment: Did you put inside <p:ajax>?

Comment: yes but the setter of the property is not called and I don't know why. I have snipped code: <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{labelsManager.onRowEdit}" >
         <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{labelsManager.currentRow}" value="test" />
        </p:ajax>   where currentRow is a property of my bean

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15876257/fsetpropertyactionlistener-doesnt-set-the-value-however-action-is-triggered It seems the f:setPropertyActionListener work only on commandButton or commandLink

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your datatable already carries the active row information via the attribute you set with `rowKey="#{label.cod}"`. This leaves you a number of options, of which the most flexible is the `getRowIndex()` variable on the `DataTable` class like so:

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {
   AjaxBehaviorEvent evt = (AjaxBehaviorEvent)event;
   (DataTable) table = evt.getSource();
    int activeRow  = table.getRowIndex(); //do whatever you want with it
}
```

Alternatively, if your list items have properly implemented `equals` and `hashCode`, you should also be able to retrieve index of the currently selected object by simply using the `indexOf` method on `List` (the ordering of items in a datatable is pretty reliable with regard to the ordering of the items in the backing list). That leaves you the option of :

```
 public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {

     Label theLabel = (Label)event.getObject(); //I'm assuming the item is of type Label
     int theIndex = labelslist.indexOf(theLabel);

 }
```

Granted, the alternative is not particularly efficient (the list needs to run thru every item to compare), but it's quite straightforward

Comment: I already did and you have absolutely right. Thank you! P.S. I can call getSource() method directly from event. I don't need evt variable

Comment: Wowww, I had no idea about it! Nice!!

Comment: Nice.  Very good answer. Congrats. P.S. You was pretty close. My object if LabelDto type :)