# Tab navigation stops on selectOneMenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces, focus, selectonemenu

I have a dataTable with cell editing enabled. When editing I would like to navigate through table content with tab key. The problem is when the focus is on a selectOneMenu column. When tab key is pressed to navigate from selectOneMenu cell onto the next cell, tab navigation stops (focus is simply lost).

Any idea how to solve this problem?

My code:

```
<p:dataTable id="tblElement" var="eltItem" value="#{bean.elementList}" binding="#{bean.dtElements}" editable="true" editMode="cell" rowKey="#{eltItem.id}" resizableColumns="true" >

    <p:column headerText="Key" toggleable="false">
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{eltItem.key}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{eltItem.key}" />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Type" >
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{eltItem.dataType.code}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{eltItem.dataType}" converter="myConverter" >
                    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.dataTypeList}" var="dt" itemLabel="#{dt.code}" itemValue="#{dt}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="Path" >
        <p:cellEditor>
            <f:facet name="output">
                <h:outputText value="#{eltItem.path}" />
            </f:facet>
            <f:facet name="input">
                <p:inputText value="#{eltItem.path}"  />
            </f:facet>
        </p:cellEditor>
    </p:column>

</p:dataTable>
```

Using PF 5.1.

Comment: huge chance this is just not supported (personally never use row or cell editing). But you might try if 5.2-SNAPSHOT or an 5.1.x elite version has improved in this regard (don't think it has though)

Comment: What do you mean, not supported? There's even a showcase on PF page  (http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml). You can tab navigate there through a second table normally.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. This happens intuitively even when using `editMode="row"`. Why are you using `binding="#{bean.dtElements}"` in `<p:dataTable>` by the way?

Comment: @Tiny I use binding for detecting index of the row that I'm editing.

Comment: This is unrelated to the concrete problem. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27967924/1391249) is one way to get a row index, if it fits your case.

Comment: Sorry, then I misunderstood... Lots of combinations in PF datatable are not supported, and since you did not write it worked in the showcase, the chance was high it would not work at all. If it does work in the showcase but not in yours, then I have no clue.

Comment: @Tiny Thanks for that information. I'm still new in PrimeFaces, so this solution could be useful for me in the future.

Comment: @Kukeltje I understand. I thought maybe it's a converter that somehow stops the tab navigation but I can't really explain why exactly...

Comment: Have you asked in the official forum? If so, please provide a link.

Comment: I did, no answer... http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=40948

Answer (score 0):

Same here.

A solution that works for me:

Use `h:selectOneMenu` instead of `p:selectOneMenu`.

Comment: But it works with `p:selectOneMenu` in the showcase... Please state version info if it did not work for you

Comment: In the showcase they also work with `h:selectOneMenu`. I use version 5.1.

Comment: Oops... correct, I was mislead by the default FireFox theme which closely resembles the default theme in the showcase! If this also does not work with PF 5.3 (maybe you can try) then please check if there is an issue that is resolved between 5.3 and the latest 6.0 SNAPSHOT, and if not, please file an issue