# datatable returns a null selected object if it is filtered primefaces 5.0

Tags: primefaces, datatable

Hope somebody may give me a hint on this case, searched a lot before posting this question with no luck.

I have a datatable that allows only a single row selection (it may include 200 rows at a time), after one is selected, a commandButton redirects the user to a new form to display some information.

The problem rises when user first applies a filter in the datatable on any given column, selects a row and clicks the commandButton, my backing bean (@ViewScoped) receives no selected object (null)

Since the form is big, here i post just part of it to display the Datatable structure:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions">

    <h:body >   
        <h:form id="Form1"> 

                <p:outputPanel id="ID1">
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
                    <tr> 
                        <td><b><big><big><font face="Arial" >#{beanD.MenuTitle} > List of records </font></big></big></b></td>
                        <td>
                            <b><big><font face="Arial"><p:outputLabel value="|" /></font></big></b>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 150px;">
                            <p:commandButton style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 13px;" icon="ui-icon-check" value="Open Record" ajax="false" 
                                         actionListener="#{MBR.Method1(2,MBR.var1.cod,MBR.var1.codS)}" action="#{beanD2.url_Menu('FormRedirected')}"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>

                    <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" border="0">
                        <tr>
                            <td>                      
                                <p:dataTable  var="Rad" selectionMode="single" value="#{MBSg.list}" 
                                              id="RSTable"  widgetVar="RS"  selection="#{MBR.var1}" rowKey="#{Rad.codS}"
                                              style="font-family: Arial;font-size: 12px; height: 320px;" emptyMessage="No Records" 
                                              scrollable="true" scrollHeight="100%;" frozenColumns="1" styleClass="FirstCol" >
                                    <p:column headerText="Header1"  filterStyle="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width:60px;" filterBy="#{Rad.field1}" filterMatchMode="contains"  style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width: 60px;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Rad.field1}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Header2" filterBy="#{Rad.field2}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width: 250px;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Rad.field2}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Header3"  filterBy="#{Rad.field3}#{Rad.entidades}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width: 900px;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Rad.field3}" />
                                    </p:column>
                                    <p:column headerText="Header4" filterBy="#{Rad.field4}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width: 100px;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Rad.field4}" />
                                    <p:column headerText="Header5"  filterStyle="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width:70px;"  filterBy="#{Rad.field5}" filterMatchMode="contains" style="font-family:Arial;font-size: 12px;width: 120px;">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{Rad.field5}" />
                                    </p:column>                                                            

                                </p:dataTable>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </p:outputPanel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

This is the method in my backing bean (MBR) that evaluates selection made by user (stored in variable var1 )

```
@ManagedBean(name = "MBR")
@ViewScoped
public class BeanR {
.
.
public void Method1(int proc, int num, int num_s) {
        try {

            if (var1 == null) {
                mbT.setMens("No item Selected");
                mbT.warn();
                mbT.resetTable("Form1:RSTable");
                ..."some other operations performed"
            } else {
                Method2(proc, num, num_s);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            mbT.setMens("Error in MBR : '" + this.getClass() + ".Method1()' caused by: " + e.getMessage());
            mbT.error();
        }

    }
}
```

As mentioned before, if selection is made after filtering ( then commandButton clicked) this message is launched in my bean: mbT.setMens("No item Selected");

By the way, filtering works fine, not problems at all.

Application is developed using Primefaces 5.0 with no chance to upgrade right now

Any work around will be appreciated, i have googled and read PrimeFaces showcases but have not found any answer,

Best regards.

**Last Update:**

After lots of tests i figured out that DataTable's Attribute **frozenColumns** was the one causing this strange behaviour when table was filtered. Hopefully any expert in StackOverflow may give us a deeper insight on the reasons behind it.

As per my problem, after removing the attribute the datatable worked fine. Hope anyone finds this usefull in future.

Comment: did you try to add an ajax event ?!? also did you make the inisialisation of your `var1`

Comment: Yagami thanks your your reply. For sure, var1 is initialized at form load.  i tried an approach using <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{MBR.Method1(2,MBR.var1.cod,MBR.var1.codS)}" process="RSTable" /> included in my datatable. Debuggin i found out that ajax event is triggered whenever a row is selected ( with or without filter ) but var1 goes null too if datatable is previously filtered. Any clue?

Comment: try to send it as a param i am sure it will work look at this example [How do you pass a value into an ajax listener primefaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472212/how-do-you-pass-a-value-into-an-ajax-listener-primefaces)

Comment: you have to send your var from the datable to an object (the same as var) and it will hold it tell me if you need more informations

Comment: No luck @Yagami ! Same behavior. this is kind of tricky :(

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue and finally figure out that I have missed the `filteredValue` attribute in the `dataTable` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Add a rowKey as a property on p:dataTable component.

```
<p:dataTable value="#{myBean.cars}" var="car" rowKey="#{car.id}">
  ...
<p:dataTable>
```